# asp.net converted to master page and no no longer see div tag

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have some pages I am converting to use master pages.  Right now just for HTML formatting, no objects/code in Master Page yet.

I have an existing page that works fine (can post if needed but kinda long) and I add a master page (like I have done on a few other pages that worked fine) and now I get an error on a div tag (in child page and reference to div is still in child page) errror:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

I am using code to get div tag:
`Control anotherDiv = Page.FindControl("divTrans")`

I know how to convert this to use Master Page just use Master.Page....

But what/how do I code this to just use the existing child page code?

Comment: It is better to leave the question as it is, and make an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do nested find controls:

```
Control anotherDiv = this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("divTrans");
```